# If i run Mobile Flex app "On Device" mode.Does the device access the database from my computer

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mobile

My application is a cloud based app.Back-end Mysql. middle-ware is Jboss.
I didn't deployed the data into cloud.but i want to run app on device,Does it can access the data base from my pc.

Answer (score 1):

The setting "on device" in Flash Builder run configurations only does one thing: It runs the app on the device you are building for.  As in: "Right now, deploy the app to my device, so I can see how it performs when it doesn't have PC hardware to run on".

I haven't deployed to Android, so I don't know for sure what goes on there, but for iOS devices, this means compiling and packaging for LLVM execution and creating a deployable .ipa package.

There are restrictions that apply for iOS: You can't load and run Flash/Flex executable code in SWF format, to name the most important one.  But Regardless of what device you are deploying to, a simple compilation setting won't create a local database to replace an external server - how could it, when its setup, characteristics and database schema aren't included anywhere in your code? And it won't disable internet connections.

Since you are probably using the internet to access your enterprise middleware, you should not run into problems.  Why don't you just give it a try?

Comment: For android, a .air file will be pushed to your phone and executed using the AIR Runtime for Android.